# mac os x - xcode cannot reach local repository

Tags: xcode, git, repository

On the recent upgrade to xcode (v4.6.2), it can no longer reach local git repositories.

This is for existing projects as well as new projects (example below is a brand new project, with the option 'xcode to create local repository' ticked.

I should clarify that the local repository is created - running git status and git log on the local directory gives the correct outputs.  But the repo appears as 'red' (i.e. missing)

[image: View from organiser]

as well as showing the message 'repository cannot be reached'
[image: doing a refresh or commit]

When I run git status, I get:

```
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   TestProj.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/
#   TestProj.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Any help is appreciated!